# Add new JDBC Datasource resource without restart

Tags: jdbc, tomcat7, datasource

In Tomcat 7, is it possible at all to configure (add/edit/remove) datasource resources (e.g. add a new jdbc datasource resource in context.xml) and make it available to new deployments without the need to re-start the Tomcat container itself? I am thinking along the lines of how Weblogic allows you to add/remove datasources without the need to re-start the container.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.
PM.

Comment: I have just noticed that if Tomcat's context.xml file is modified while the container is running, the container itself is fully re-started? Is this correct? Does this mean that all deployments in the container are re-started if say a new datasource resource is included in context.xml?

Comment: If I set autoDeploy="false" in server.xml, then the container will not auto-restart upon modifying context.xml. This way, I can un-deploy and re-deploy a WAR file itself forcing it to pick up the modified resource(s) within context.xml. Although this answers my question, I am wondering whether there is a better way to manage datasources in Tomcat? Cheers, PM.

Comment: I am interested in how you finally did it. I have separate context files for each war on tomcat. I want to add a global DS want it to be available to the application without redeploying the applications. Right now the application's context picks the global DS only when I redeploy the application.

Comment: Hi @Ashley, we have currently have got one global context file for all deployed apps. If the global context file is changed, then each deployed app interested in the change needs to be re-deployed either automatically (default) or manually (when autoDeploy="false" in server.xml).